# How to use dbdeploy with SQL Server?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, dbdeploy

I need help in setting up dbdeploy for my SQL Server database and MySQL Server.

The example in the dbdeploy website does not tell me how to set the drivers for SQL Server and MySQL. Am a bit lost.

Sample scripts will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: do you have a link for "dbdeploy" ?

Comment: Sorry, link to dbdeploy is http://dbdeploy.com/

Answer (score 1):

As part of some [ReadyRoll](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/readyroll/) market research we commissioned a poll in the Simple Talk newsletter which revealed that [DBUp](https://dbup.github.io/) is now the most adopted database migrations tool after EF migrations, so it would be worth considering this solution as an alternative to DBDeploy.

(Simple Talk's audience is primarily people who use the .NET/SQL Server stack)

Disclaimer: I work for Redgate and the research described above was focused on understanding how ReadyRoll could provide additional value on existing OSS migrations-based solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use dbdeploy for my project with MSSQL 2008
But I didn't like it and now for MS SQL we use [Agile DBRIRE](http://www.thisisagile.com/dbrire)